# Usb keyboard connected on windows, sending keystrokes to linux tty over Lan

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, keyboard, ethernet

My current set up, i have a usb keyboard connected to a windows machine, I have linux machine on Lan which has a monitor but is NOT running X.org, (synergy won't work for me).

I was wondering is there a pre-existing driver for linux which can receive key strokes over Ethernet and emulate as if a local keyboard was  being used.

(I can write the windows drivers as needed, but I don't know how linux drivers work yet..)

Answer (score 0):

[Use netcat to pipe from a socket](https://superuser.com/a/70657/26316) to the [uinput device](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput), and then have the Windows machine send [input events](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt) to the socket.